# Calendar not showing today's date and time using malot datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, smalot-datetimepicker

I wanted to show the current up-to-date datetimepicker, but it only shows a few hour late from the current time. For now, I am using the `endDate` to restrict the limit to 'today'.

I am using malot datetimepicker from here: https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="dtp_input4" class="control-label">Start Time</label>
    <div class="input-group date form_starttime" data-date="" data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:ii" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
        <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly data-ng-model="startDT">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-times" id="remove"></span></span>
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.form_starttime').datetimepicker({
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    format: 'yyyy.mm.dd HH:ii',
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    endDate: '+0d',
})
.on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('.form_endtime').datetimepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});
```

**Image**

The current time at the moment I posted this was 1548, but it only shows up till 0700.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the html code too

Comment: what is your time zone??

Comment: @ashish yadav GMT+8

Comment: You have to pass `startDate` property with your current time-zone time.

Comment: which country you are in,... what is the time right now

Comment: I'm currently in Malaysia and it's 1644 now

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have error in format it should be `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii`

this is how the examples are defined in documentation and format is given as

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii"
    });
</script>
```

I believe your format in html and script is not matching as it is working fine for me also, try changing that I would suggest.

Comment: The format does not change the selection to current time

Comment: ya format given in documentation is like this so it should work .

Comment: I am using the time stamp for that particular format, otherwise it will give me an error storing information.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourTimeZone = = moment.tz("2016-10-07 12:00", "Asia/Ulaanbaatar");
yourTimeZone.format() // returns "2016-10-07T12:00:00+08:00"
```

You have to pass `startDate:2016-10-07T12:00:00+08:00` property with your current time-zone time.

Please change "`Asia/Ulaanbaatar`" to your country

check here for [timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)